# Azure Dependency Agent failing to write to Log Analytics Workspace

Tags: azure, log-analytics-workspace

I am working to get the Azure Dependency Agent, installed on an Arc enabled Windows 2019 server, reporting to an Azure Log Analytics workspace. I have enabled the [Preview]: Enable Azure Monitor for Hybrid VMs with AMA initiative to accomplish this.

The Azure Connected Machine (azcmagent.exe) is reporting heartbeat messages to the LAW. The Azure Monitoring Agent has been installed by an extension and I am seeing data in the Event and Perf tables of the LAW.

The Azure Dependency Agent is also installed by an extension but no data is showing in the LAW. Inspecting the MicrosoftDependencyAgent.log in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dependency Agent\logs, I am seeing lots of messages like the following:

2023-04-10 15:13:30.026-{WARN}-AMA: Unable to get channel code: 2, message=The system cannot find the file specified. on path \.\pipe\CAgentStream_CloudAgentInfo_AzureMonitorAgent

What is wrong? How can I get the dependency agent reporting to the Log Analytics Workspace?